# Is it possible to set SVG object coordinates as a changing variable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, svg, positioning

I'm creating svg using HTML and JavaSCript and I want to add some new svg objects into it based on onclick function. And I wonder if it is possible to set new SVG's coordinates as a changing variable.
My idea goes like this:

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg id="board" width="360" height="360">
            <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="130" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="250" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>

            <rect x="10" y="130" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="130" y="130" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="250" y="130" width="100" height="100"/>

            <rect x="10" y="250" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="130" y="250" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="250" y="250" width="100" height="100"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
```

#### JS

```
window.onclick = function(event){
    const CX = event.pageX;
    const CY = event.pageY;
    [...]
        
    drawImage();
}

[...]

function drawImage(){

    let coordX = CX/(360/3);         //360 is a size of the SVG object
    let coordY = CY/(360/3);

    function addCircle(){
        const circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
        circle.setAttribute("cx", coordX);
        circle.setAttribute("cy", coordY);
        circle.setAttribute("r", "45");
        circle.setAttribute("stroke", "blue");
        circle.setAttribute("stroke-width", "10");
        circle.setAttribute("fill", "#FCF8C4");

        document.getElementById("board").appendChild(circle);
    }
}
```

I want to visualize the newly drawed SVG based onclick at particular place. Is this even possible to do it this way?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Well, the `circle` does not render onclick at the SVG. And I don't know if I can make it this way (appendChiid) or the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Wodnerful, thank you very much Robert, your solution seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work if you fix the errors in the script i.e.

- you need to pass CX and CY to drawImage
- you need to actually call addCircle
- you can just use CX and CY directly

```js
window.onclick = function(event){
                const CX = event.pageX;
                const CY = event.pageY;


        drawImage(CX, CY);
        }

function drawImage(CX, CY){

    let coordX = CX;
    let coordY = CY;

        function addCircle(){

            const circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
            circle.setAttribute("cx", coordX);
            circle.setAttribute("cy", coordY);
            circle.setAttribute("r", "45");
            circle.setAttribute("stroke", "blue");
            circle.setAttribute("stroke-width", "10");
            circle.setAttribute("fill", "#FCF8C4");

            document.getElementById("board").appendChild(circle);
        }
        addCircle();
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg id="board" width="360" height="360">
            <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="130" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="250" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>

            <rect x="10" y="130" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="130" y="130" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="250" y="130" width="100" height="100"/>

            <rect x="10" y="250" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="130" y="250" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="250" y="250" width="100" height="100"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
```

Comment: or maybe `window.onclick = drawImage`

Comment: That would work in my example answer but the question would seem to have additional elided things other than drawImage that the OP wants to call.